# How to create Channel Factory

Tags: c#, wcf

Hi I'm trying to call a WCF service from within console application, and return this:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The underlying channel factory could not be created because no Binding was passed to the ChannelFactory.

My code:

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxxx/xxxx/FormulationService");

var servis = new ChannelFactory<IFormulasyonHost>().CreateChannel(address);
((IServiceChannel)servis).Open();

if (args[0].ToString() == "-update")
{
   if (args[1].ToString() == "all")
   {
      servis.UpdateAll();
      ((IServiceChannel)servis).Close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the basic binding is used

```
var address = ...
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

var servis = new ChannelFactory<IFormulasyonHost>(binding,address)
    .CreateChannel();
```